# Neo4j complex dynamic relationship creation with batch iteration

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query that I've been working on. Basically I have two sets of class type nodes, one called Genes and the other n4sch__Class, the Genes have a parameter 'GO ID' that links them to the class category name. After getting all matching class nodes I want to create a relationship that is also based on the Gene nodes parameter 'Qualifier', and this parameter is dynamic so I need to use apoc.create.relationship. The query is also rather large so it needs to be batched. This is what I have so far but it is returning an error:

`call apoc.periodic.iterate( "MATCH (n:Genes),(c:n4sch__Class) WHERE n.`GO ID `= c.n4sch__name RETURN n,c", "WITH n, c,  CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, n.Qualifier, {}, c) YIELD rel RETURN rel",{batchMode: "BATCH_SINGLE", BatchSize:100})`

"Invalid input 'apoc': expected ...(line 2, column 6 (offset: 17))\r\n"CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, n.Qualifier, {}, c) YIELD rel RETURN rel"\r\n      ^": 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your query:

- There is an illegal comma between the (unneeded) `WITH` clause and the following `CALL` clause.
- You used the `batchMode: "BATCH_SINGLE"`
  option but still expected the second Cypher statement to be able to
  access `n` and `c` directly.

*Apparently, you did actually have backticks around the property name "GO ID" -- to make the space character usable as part of the name. But for some reason the backticks were not visible characters in your question.*

When you use the [BATCH_SINGLE](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/#_batch_mode_batch_single) mode, an entire batch of `n` and `c` values are provided to the second Cypher statement via the `$_batch` parameter, as a list of results (e.g., `[{n: <node1>, c: <node2>}, {n: <node3>, c: <node4>}, ...]`).

You can just omit the `batchMode` option to get the default behavior, which is the one you expected:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "MATCH (n:Genes),(c:n4sch__Class)
     WHERE n.`GO ID` = c.n4sch__name
     RETURN n, c",
    "CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, n.Qualifier, {}, c) YIELD rel
     RETURN rel",
     {batchSize:100}
)
```